# What does Deadpool mean by "left the house in that shirt"?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool-2

Deadpool tosses himself from building. A passerby sees him
and comments:

> Passerby: I can't believe he's still alive.
>
> Deadpool: [I can't believe you **left the house in that shirt**](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/21f815a4-dd96-4ec5-b902-8363df10c486).

What does it mean by "left the house in that shirt"?

Comment: This looks like an [ell.se] question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on English Language Learners.

Comment: Reopened: [our policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11626/31394) is that questions about the meaning of quotes from works of sci-fi and fantasy are on-topic here. On-topicness on other sites is irrelevant to deciding *our* site scope (otherwise we'd send nearly everything to either [movies.se] or [literature.se]). cc @DanielRoseman

Comment: If you're still wondering what it means, it means "I can't believe you left the house while (still) wearing that shirt"

Comment: @Randal'Thor what then stops asking a question for every single line of every SciFi work asking what it means?

Comment: @OrangeDog The same thing as stops asking a question for e.g. why every single character in Harry Potter was Sorted as they were, or for the significance of the name of every single character in every SF/F work, or any other category of on-topic question. Being mass-producible doesn't make something off-topic.

Comment: @OrangeDog those might be bad questions which should be downvoted. But they would still be on-topic.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It means that Deadpool finds the shirt so ugly or unfashionable or unflattering that he can't believe that someone would actually leave their home and be seen in public wearing it.

Answer (score 5):

It's his brand of humor combined with him trivializing his fall. First, he's dismissing the fall as anything worthy of comment. Second, he's displaying his attitude - insulting pretty much anyone, especially anyone he doesn't like.

Comment: I don't think this counts as an example of "insulting pretty much anyone"; it's an example of counter-insulting someone who targeted a comment at him. "I can't believe you survived that fall." "Shut up, I can't believe your mum survived that fall." Though it is of course completely in character.